# laravel search json data

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.8 and one of the column named `meta` contains json data which store data as `{"form_id":31}`

I want to get all the record that matches this form_id.
I did something like this and it is not working

```
  $formId = request()->id;
   $query->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS("meta" ', $formId));
```

I have to filter from meta column

table structure

```
id meta
1 {"form_id":31}
2  {"form_id":31}
3 {"form_id":32}
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel supports querying JSON column types on databases that provide support for JSON column types like mysql ....

```
 $query->whereJsonContains('meta->form_id",$formId);
```

and if you want exact comparison you can use:

```
$query->where('meta->form_id",$formId);
```

more info in [Laravel 5.8 doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses)